# downloading specific files resides in s3 subfolder into my local machine using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a file resides in a s3 bucket subfolder. Bucket name "testbucket", folder name-"folder1". File name:"sample.csv". I want to download that into my local machine: "/Users/sameer/desktop/folder1".

What is the most efficient way to do download that if the file size is more than 3gb

Comment: Probably best to download the aws cli and run it from the command line.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130448/how-to-access-a-file-on-amazon-s3-from-the-command-line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a file on Amazon S3 from the Command Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130448/how-to-access-a-file-on-amazon-s3-from-the-command-line)

Comment: The requirement is to download via python boto3 script

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/downloading-large-files-from-amazon-s3-with-the-aws-sdk-for-ios/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442444/download-s3-files-with-boto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AWS CLI

```sh
aws s3 cp s3://testbucket/folder1/sample.csv /Users/sameer/desktop/folder1
```

if you must boto3:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

s3_client.download_file('testbucket', 'folder1/sample.csv', '/Users/sameer/desktop/folder1/sample.csv')
```