# batch copy between S3 buckets

Tags: python, amazon-s3, copy, boto3

I would like to copy a list of files from one S3 bucket to another.

Iterating over the files and using boto3 "bucket.copy" [(link)](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy) function is very slow.

Is there a way to perform a batch copy or speed things up?

Comment: What do you mean "bucket.copy" is slow?  Can you show the copying code?  Normally, you should use system wide copy , e.g. s3transfer file copy, instead of reading the content and transfer it.

Comment: @mootmoot, i mean http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy

Comment: Please look into async copy , python asyncio.

Comment: I'll look into it. also found this: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) has a `aws s3 sync` option that recursively copies new and updated files from the source directory to the destination.

See: [Sync documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

For recursive copy using python, refer to: [Boto3 to download all files from a S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33350380/4840338)

Comment: I would recommend *against* downloading files. You can tell Amazon S3 to perform bucket-to-bucket copies, which is much faster.