# AWS CLI Download list of S3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

We have ~400,000 files on a private S3 bucket that are inbound/outbound call recordings.  The files have a certain pattern to it that lets me search for numbers both inbound and outbound.  Note these calls are on the *Glacier* storage class

Using AWS CLI, I can search through this bucket and grep the files I need out.  What I'd like to do is now initiate an S3 restore job to expedited retrieval (so ~1-5 minute recovery time), and then maybe 30 minutes later run a command to download the files.

My efforts so far:

```
aws s3 ls s3://exetel-logs/ --recursive | grep .*042222222.* | cut -c 32-
```

Retreives the key of about 200 files.  I am unsure of how to proceed next, as `aws s3 cp` wont work for any objects in storage class.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

The AWS CLI has two separate commands for S3: `s3` and`s3api`. `s3` is a high level abstraction with limited features, so for restoring files, you'll have to use one of the commands available with `s3api`:

```
aws s3api restore-object --bucket exetel-logs --key your-key
```

If you afterwards want to copy the files, but want to ensure to only copy files which were restored from Glacier, you can use the following code snippet:

```
for key in $(aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket exetel-logs --query "Contents[?StorageClass=='GLACIER'].[Key]" --output text); do
  if [ $(aws s3api head-object --bucket exetel-logs --key ${key} --query "contains(Restore, 'ongoing-request=\"false\"')") == true ]; then
    echo ${key}
  fi
done
```

Comment: Great answer, except that objects restored from glacier storage class shouldn't subsequently show as `STANDARD`.  That doesn't seem possible, for a couple of different reasons.  I don't think there's a way to differentiate restoration status from an object listing.  A `head-object` should be needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I fixed the code snippet in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a high-level language wrapper for the AWS CLI? It will make these kinds of tasks easier to integrate into your workflows. I prefer the Python implementation (Boto 3). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918960/boto3-to-download-all-files-from-a-s3-bucket) is example code for how to download all files from an S3 bucket.