# Download a folder from S3 using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, boto3

Using `Boto3 Python SDK`, I was able to download files using the method `bucket.download_file()`

Is there a way to download an entire folder?

Comment: Possibly duplicate- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918960/boto3-to-download-all-files-from-a-s3-bucket/31960438

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boto3 to download all files from a S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918960/boto3-to-download-all-files-from-a-s3-bucket)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

quick and dirty but it works:

```py
import boto3
import os 

def downloadDirectoryFroms3(bucketName, remoteDirectoryName):
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucketName) 
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix = remoteDirectoryName):
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(obj.key)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(obj.key))
        bucket.download_file(obj.key, obj.key) # save to same path
```

Assuming you want to download the directory foo/bar from s3 then the for-loop will iterate all the files whose path starts with the Prefix=foo/bar.

Comment: But you didn't set credentials!

Comment: @Arkady

The credentials are set under ~/.aws/credentials or as Environment variables

You can find more info [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html)

Comment: Credentials can be set in different ways. See https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html?highlight=credentials

Comment: you can declare aws credentials when creating s3 resource as following 
 `s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key) `

Comment: I posted a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64226700/download-entire-content-of-a-subfolder-in-a-s3-bucket is your suggested answer the best way i can solve my problem ?

Comment: Well there is almost never absolute best :).

Comment: to make this recursive (for directories inside directories), only download file if not obj.key.endswith('/'):

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to avoid when looking this up

Answer (score 53):

A slightly less dirty modification of the accepted answer by Konstantinos Katsantonis:

```py
import boto3
import os
s3 = boto3.resource('s3') # assumes credentials & configuration are handled outside python in .aws directory or environment variables

def download_s3_folder(bucket_name, s3_folder, local_dir=None):
    """
    Download the contents of a folder directory
    Args:
        bucket_name: the name of the s3 bucket
        s3_folder: the folder path in the s3 bucket
        local_dir: a relative or absolute directory path in the local file system
    """
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=s3_folder):
        target = obj.key if local_dir is None \
            else os.path.join(local_dir, os.path.relpath(obj.key, s3_folder))
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(target)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(target))
        if obj.key[-1] == '/':
            continue
        bucket.download_file(obj.key, target)
```

This downloads nested subdirectories, too.  I was able to download a directory with over 3000 files in it.  You'll find other solutions at [Boto3 to download all files from a S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918960/boto3-to-download-all-files-from-a-s3-bucket/31929277), but I don't know if they're any better.

Answer (score 20):

You could also use [`cloudpathlib`](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/) which, for S3, wraps `boto3`. For your use case, it's pretty simple:

```py
from cloudpathlib import CloudPath

cp = CloudPath("s3://bucket/folder/folder2/")
cp.download_to("local_folder")
```

Comment: does somebody know, if AWS counts this as one request for the billing?!

Comment: Probably not. It should work out to about same as looping over each key with `boto3` (maybe with an added call to list objects, but you need that in both cases)

Comment: for me it only worked without the trailing `/`... in the example above it would be: `cp = CloudPath("s3://bucket/folder/folder2")`

Comment: @hume Can I pass the relative path to the CloudPath. For example: "s3://bucket/*/*/device/" ?

Comment: @trungducng There is a `glob` method like with a normal `Path` that you can use to loop over those files and call `download_to` on each one individually. https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/stable/api-reference/s3path/#cloudpathlib.s3.s3path.S3Path.glob

Comment: Why isn't this the top solution!! This tool is awesome.

Answer (score 5):

Using `boto3` you can set aws credentials and download dataset from S3

```py
import boto3
import os 

# set aws credentials 
s3r = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
bucket = s3r.Bucket('bucket_name')

# downloading folder 
prefix = 'dirname'
for object in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix = 'dirname'):
    if object.key == prefix:
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(object.key), exist_ok=True)
        continue;
    bucket.download_file(object.key, object.key)
```

If you cannot find ur `access_key` and `secret_access_key`, refer to this [page](https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/security/wheres-my-secret-access-key/)  
I hope it will helps. 
thank you.

Comment: Better to avoid putting your keys in your code file. At worst, you can put your keys in a separate protected file and import them. It's also possible to use boto3 without any credentials cached and instead use either s3fs or just rely on the config file (https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/73212m/has_anyone_found_a_way_to_hide_boto3_credentials/)

Answer (score 5):

Another approach building on the answer from @bjc that leverages the built in Path library and parses the s3 uri for you:

```
import boto3
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def download_s3_folder(s3_uri, local_dir=None):
    """
    Download the contents of a folder directory
    Args:
        s3_uri: the s3 uri to the top level of the files you wish to download
        local_dir: a relative or absolute directory path in the local file system
    """
    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    bucket = s3.Bucket(urlparse(s3_uri).hostname)
    s3_path = urlparse(s3_uri).path.lstrip('/')
    if local_dir is not None:
        local_dir = Path(local_dir)
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=s3_path):
        target = obj.key if local_dir is None else local_dir / Path(obj.key).relative_to(s3_path)
        target.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        if obj.key[-1] == '/':
            continue
        bucket.download_file(obj.key, str(target))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call the awscli cp command from python to download an entire folder

```
 import os
 import subprocess

 remote_folder_name = 's3://my-bucket/my-dir'
 local_path = '.'
 if not os.path.exists(local_path):
     os.makedirs(local_path)
 subprocess.run(['aws', 's3', 'cp', remote_folder_name, local_path, '--recursive'])
```

Some notes regarding this solution:

1. You should install awscli (`pip install awscli`) and configure it. more info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)
2. If you don't want to override existing files if they weren't changed, you can use `sync` instead of `cp` `subprocess.run(['aws', 's3', 'sync', remote_folder_name, local_path])`
3. Tested on python 3.6. on earlier versions of python you might need to replace `subprocess.run` with `subprocess.call` or `os.system`
4. The cli command that is executed by this code is `aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/my-dir . --recursive`

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions are good, and rely on S3 Resource.
The following solution, achieves the same goal, but with applying s3_client.
You might find it useful for your end (I've tested it, and it works well).

```
import boto3
from os import path, makedirs
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from boto3.exceptions import S3TransferFailedError

def download_s3_folder(s3_folder, local_dir, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_bucket, debug_en):
    """ Download the contents of a folder directory into a local area """

    success = True

    print('[INFO] Downloading %s from bucket %s...' % (s3_folder, aws_bucket))

    def get_all_s3_objects(s3, **base_kwargs):
        continuation_token = None
        while True:
            list_kwargs = dict(MaxKeys=1000, **base_kwargs)
            if continuation_token:
                list_kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = continuation_token
            response = s3.list_objects_v2(**list_kwargs)
            yield from response.get('Contents', [])
            if not response.get('IsTruncated'):
                break
            continuation_token = response.get('NextContinuationToken')

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                             aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                             aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)

    all_s3_objects_gen = get_all_s3_objects(s3_client, Bucket=aws_bucket)

    for obj in all_s3_objects_gen:
        source = obj['Key']
        if source.startswith(s3_folder):
            destination = path.join(local_dir, source)
            if not path.exists(path.dirname(destination)):
                makedirs(path.dirname(destination))
            try:
                s3_client.download_file(aws_bucket, source, destination)
            except (ClientError, S3TransferFailedError) as e:
                print('[ERROR] Could not download file "%s": %s' % (source, e))
                success = False
            if debug_en:
                print('[DEBUG] Downloading: %s --> %s' % (source, destination))

    return success
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with this version.
Modified variable destination and included variable for filter to files type.

```
from sre_constants import SUCCESS
import boto3 
from os import path, makedirs 
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from boto3.exceptions import S3TransferFailedError

def download_s3_folder(s3_folder, local_dir, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_bucket, debug_en, datatype):
""""" Download the contents of a folder directory into a local area """""

success = True
# Start do processo de copia
print('[INFO] Downloading %s from bucket %s...' % (s3_folder, aws_bucket))

# Metodo que lista todos os objetos do Bucket. 
def get_all_s3_objects(s3, **base_kwargs):
    continuation_token = None
    while True:
        list_kwargs = dict(MaxKeys=1000, **base_kwargs)
        if continuation_token:
            list_kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = continuation_token
        response = s3.list_objects_v2(**list_kwargs)
        yield from response.get('Contents', [])
        if not response.get('IsTruncated'):
            break
        continuation_token = response.get('NextContinuationToken')

s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                         aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)

all_s3_objects_gen = get_all_s3_objects(s3_client, Bucket=aws_bucket)

# Loop into os objetos do S3,
for obj in all_s3_objects_gen:
    source = obj['Key']
    if source.startswith(s3_folder):
        # Transform path to using fo SO
        destination = path.join(local_dir,source).replace('/','\\')
        
        if not path.exists(path.dirname(destination)):
            makedirs(path.dirname(destination))
        try:
            #print('copy')
            if destination.endswith(datatype):
                #print(destination)
                print('Copia do arquivo "%s" Sucesso' % (destination))
                s3_client.download_file(aws_bucket, source, destination)
        except (ClientError, S3TransferFailedError) as e:
            print('[ERROR] Could not download file "%s": %s' % (source, e))
            success = False
        if debug_en:
            print(f"[DEBUG] Downloading: {source} --> {destination}")

return success
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I've written a script to download any files with any extension (.csv in the code), you can change the file extension according to the type of files you need to download

```
import boto3
import os
import shutil

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id='',
    aws_secret_access_key='',
)


def download_directory(bucket_name, s3_folder_name):
    s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
    objs = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=s3_folder_name))
    for obj in objs:
        print("Try to Downloading " + obj.key)
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(obj.key)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(obj.key))
        out_name = obj.key.split('/')[-1]
        if out_name[-4:] == ".csv":
            bucket.download_file(obj.key, out_name)
            print(f"Downloaded {out_name}")
            dest_path = ('/').join(obj.key.split('/')[0:-1])
            shutil.move(out_name, dest_path)
            print(f"Moved File to {dest_path}")
        else:
            print(f"Skipping {out_name}")


download_directory("mybucket", "myfolder")
```

Please feel free to ask me for help if you can't understand what to do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I hope, it will give you a better understanding of uploading, downloading and getting an s3 object

```
# libraries import
import boto3
import pandas as pd

# configure aws on command line
# aws configure
# enter your access key, access secret and region in which you create your bucket
# You get your access key and access password from security credentials under the iam
# if its disabled delete the previous one and then create the new one

s3_obj = boto3.client("s3") # object for accessing s3

# Downloading file code
s3_obj.download_file(
    Filename="./local_file_name_which_you_download_from_s3.csv",
    Bucket="your_bucket_name",
    Key="file_in_s3_bucket.csv"
# )
df = pd.read_csv('./local_file_name_which_you_download_from_s3.csv')
df.head()

# Uploading file code
s3_obj.upload_file(
    Filename="./local_file_name_which_you_download_from_s3.csv",
    Bucket="your_bucket_name",
    Key="file_in_s3_bucket.csv"
)

s3_obj_file = s3_obj.get_object(Bucket='bucket_name', Key='file_in_s3_bucket')['Body'].read()
df_upload = pd.read_excel(s3_obj_file)
df_upload.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach inspired by [konstantinos-katsantonis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2429426/bjc) and [bjc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2429426/bjc) answers.

```
import os
import boto3
from pathlib import Path

def download_s3_dir(bucketName, remote_dir, local_dir):
    assert remote_dir.endswith('/')
    assert local_dir.endswith('/')
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucketName) 
    objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=remote_dir)
    sorted_objs = sorted(objs, key=attrgetter("key"))
    for obj in sorted_objs:
        path = Path(os.path.dirname(local_dir + obj.key))
        path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        if not obj.key.endswith("/"):
            bucket.download_file(obj.key, str(path) + "/" + os.path.split(obj.key)[1])
```

Comment: It does not work for me. I get:
`AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [34], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 download_s3_dir(bucket_name, remote_folder_name, local_path)

Input In [23], in download_s3_dir(bucketName, remote_dir, local_dir)
      5 def download_s3_dir(bucketName, remote_dir, local_dir):
      6     assert remote_dir.endswith('/')
----> 7     assert local_dir.endswith('/')
      8     s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
      9     bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucketName) 

AssertionError:`

Comment: @user88484, mare sure your remote_dir and loca_dir endswith a '/'