# Download file from AWS S3 using Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, boto3

I am trying to download a file from Amazon S3 bucket to my local using the below code but I get an error saying "Unable to locate credentials"

Given below is the code I have written:

```
from boto3.session import Session
import boto3

ACCESS_KEY = 'ABC'
SECRET_KEY = 'XYZ'

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
              aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
your_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')

for s3_file in your_bucket.objects.all():
    print(s3_file.key) # prints the contents of bucket

s3 = boto3.client ('s3')

s3.download_file('your_bucket','k.png','/Users/username/Desktop/k.png')
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You are not using the session you created to download the file, you're using s3 client you created. If you want to use the client you need to specify credentials.

```
your_bucket.download_file('k.png', '/Users/username/Desktop/k.png')
```

or

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=... , aws_secret_access_key=...)
s3.download_file('your_bucket','k.png','/Users/username/Desktop/k.png')
```

Comment: @Joaquin please add documentation to where you found this for a more complete answer. Nevertheless +1

Answer (score 33):

From an [example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html) in the [official documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html), the correct format is:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=... , aws_secret_access_key=...)
s3.download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'FILE_NAME')
```

You can also use a file-like object opened in binary mode.

```py
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=... , aws_secret_access_key=...)
with open('FILE_NAME', 'wb') as f:
    s3.download_fileobj('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', f)
    f.seek(0)
```

---

The code in question uses `s3 = boto3.client ('s3')`, which does not provide any credentials.

The format for authenticating a client is shown [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#method-parameters):

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
)

# Or via the Session
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
)
```

---

And lastly you can also re-use the authenticated [session](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/session.html) you created to get the [bucket](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket), and then [download then file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_file) from the bucket.

```py
from boto3.session import Session
import boto3

ACCESS_KEY = 'ABC'
SECRET_KEY = 'XYZ'

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
              aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

# session is authenticated and can access the resource in question 
session.resource('s3')
    .Bucket('bucket_name')
    .download_file('k.png','/Users/username/Desktop/k.png')
```

Comment: For your use of `download_fileobj` may I suggest you add the line: `f.seek(0)`. The file is left in an non-deterministic state. This line ensures you start reading it back from the beginning (just spent some time figuring this out myself!)

Comment: @RobertKing do you mind elaborating on this point? Why add `f.seek(0)`?

Answer (score 2):

For others trying to download files from AWS S3 looking for a more user-friendly solution with other industrial-strength features, check out https://github.com/d6t/d6tpipe. It abstracts the S3 functions into a simpler interface. It also supports directory sync, uploading files, permissions and many other things you need to sync files from S3 (and ftp).

```
import d6tpipe
api = d6tpipe.api.APILocal() # keep permissions locally for security

settings = \
{
    'name': 'my-files',
    'protocol': 's3',
    'location': 'bucket-name',
    'readCredentials' : {
        'aws_access_key_id': 'AAA',
        'aws_secret_access_key': 'BBB'
    }
}

d6tpipe.api.create_pipe_with_remote(api, settings)

pipe = d6tpipe.Pipe(api, 'my-files')
pipe.scan_remote() # show all files
pipe.pull_preview() # preview
pipe.pull(['k.png']) # download single file
pipe.pull() # download all files

pipe.files() # show files
file=open(pipe.dirpath/'k.png') # access file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can setup your AWS profile with awscli to avoid introduce your credentials in the file. First add your profile:

```
aws configure --profile account1
```

Then in your code add:

```
aws_session = boto3.Session(profile_name="account1")
s3_client = aws_session.client('s3')
```

Answer (score 0):

### FileName:

can be any name; with that name; file will be downloaded.
It can be added to any existing local directory.

### Key:

Is the S3 file path along with the file name in the end.
It does not start with a backslash.

### Session()

It automatically picks the credentials from `~/.aws/config` OR `~/.aws/credentials`

If not you need to explicitly pass that.

```
from boto3.session import Session
import boto3

# Let's use Amazon S3
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")

# Print out bucket names to check you have accessibility
# for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
#     print(bucket.name)

session = Session()
OR
session = Session(aws_access_key_id="AKIAYJN2LNOU",
                  aws_secret_access_key="wMyT0SxEOsoeiHYVO3v9Gc",
                  region_name="eu-west-1")    

session.resource('s3').Bucket('bucket-logs').download_file(Key="logs/20221122_0_5ee03da676ac566336e2279decfc77b3.gz", Filename="/tmp/Local_file_name.gz")
```