# Is there a easy way to get files from S3 by python?

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I tried to create a script which get a file from specific Bucket in S3, 
**for example:** from `"s3://my-bucket/veryCoolFile.img"` I want to get veryCoolFile.img
 what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file from AWS S3 using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100221/download-file-from-aws-s3-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python have boto3 which its API to most (if not all) the operations in AWS.
the way to do your mission could be done by the next code:

```
def get_file_fore_s3(bucket,file_name):
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = <YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID>
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = <YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    all_objects = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket= bucket)
    for object in all_objects['Contents']:
        current_file_name = object['Key]
        if file_name == current_file_name:
            f = open(file_name, "w+")
            f.close()
            s3_resource.meta.client.download_file(bucket, file_name,file_name)
```

The idea behind the solution is to get the bucket element (which describe by all_objects im my code)
and iterate over the "Content" of the bucket.