# how to specify destination for s3 bucket download python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

how to specify destination path for the downloaded file?

```
    s3 = boto3.resource(..)
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(S3_BUCKET)
    # download file into current directory
    for s3_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
        path, filename = os.path.split(s3_object.key)
        my_bucket.download_file(s3_object.key, filename)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100221/download-file-from-aws-s3-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
my_bucket.download_file(s3_object.key, filename)
```

the `filename` parameter specifies where to save the object on the local disk.

The `Key` of an object in Amazon S3 can include a path, such as `january/invoice.txt`. However, this line in your code:

```
path, filename = os.path.split(s3_object.key)
```

is splitting-out the path from the filename, leaving `path = january/` and `filename = invoice.txt`.

Therefore, when your code is saving objects, it will be saving them **in the current directory**.

To modify this, you should specify a full path in the `filename`, such as:

```
my_bucket.download_file(s3_object.key, '/tmp/' + filename)
```

Things get a bit more complex when you want to preserve the directory structure. For example, there might be multiple files with the same name:

```
january/invoice.txt
february/invoice.txt
```

The existing code would **overwrite** the first `invoice.txt` with the second one. If you wish to preserve the directory structure, your code would *not* call `os.path.split` but would instead need to ensure that each destination directory already exists.

For an example, see: [Download a folder from S3 using Boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54672690/174777)