# How to download multiple files via Flask and boto3 from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, flask, response, boto3

I have a list of .zip files on S3 which is dynamically created and passed to flask view /download. My problem doesn't seem to be in looping through this list, but rather in returning a response so that all files from the list are downloaded to users computer. If I have a view return a response it only downloads the first file, as return closes the connection. 
I have tried a number of things and looked at similar issues (like this one: [Boto3 to download all files from a S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918960/boto3-to-download-all-files-from-a-s3-bucket) ), but so far had no luck in resolving this.  I have also looked at streaming (as in here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/streaming/ ) and tried creating a subfunction which is a generator, but the same issue persists as I still have to pass a return value to View function - here is that last code example:

```
@app.route('/download', methods=['POST'])
def download():
  download=[]
  download = request.form.getlist('checked')
  def generate(result):
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(S3_BUCKET)
    d_object = my_bucket.Object(result).get()
    yield d_object['Body'].read()
  for filename in download:
    return Response (generate(filename), mimetype='application/zip', headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=' + filename})
```

What would be the best way of doing this so that all the files are downloaded?
Is there an easier way to pass a list to boto3 or any other flask module to download those files?