# how to download files from s3 bucket based on files modified date?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to download files from a particular s3 bucket based on files Last modified date.

I have researched on how to connect boto3 and there is plenty of code and documentation available for downloading the file without any conditions. I made a pseudo code

```py
def download_file_s3(bucket_name,modified_date)
    # connect to reseource s3
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id='demo', aws_secret_access_key='demo')

    # connect to the desired bucket
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

    # Get files 
    for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
```

I want to complete this function, basically, passing a modified date the function returns the files in the s3 bucket for that particular modified date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a Better solution or a function which could do this automatically. Just pass In the Bucket name and Download path name.

```
from boto3.session import Session
from datetime import date, timedelta
import boto3
import re


def Download_pdf_specifc_date_subfolder(bucket_name,download_path)
    ACCESS_KEY = 'XYZ'
    SECRET_KEY = 'ABC'
    Bucket_name=bucket_name

    # code to create a session 
    session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
              aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(Bucket_name)

    # code to get the yesterdays date
    yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
    x=yesterday.strftime('20%y-%m-%d')
    print(x)

    #code to add the files to a list which needs to be downloaded
    files_to_downloaded = []
    #code to take all the files from s3 under a specific bucket
    for fileObject in bucket.objects.all():
        file_name = str(fileObject.key)
        last_modified=str(fileObject.last_modified)
        last_modified=last_modified.split()
        if last_modified[0]==x:
    # Enter the specific bucketname in the regex in place of Airports to filter only the particluar subfolder
            if re.findall(r"Airports/[a-zA-Z]+", file_name):
                files_to_downloaded.append(file_name)

     # code to Download into a specific Folder 
    for fileObject in bucket.objects.all():
        file_name = str(fileObject.key)
        if file_name in files_to_downloaded:
            print(file_name)
            d_path=download_path + file_name
            print(d_path)
            bucket.download_file(file_name,d_path)

Download_pdf_specifc_date_subfolder(bucket_name,download_path)
```

Ultimately the function will give the results in the specific Folder with the files to be downloaded.

Comment: This solves my exact problem, in the function format. This will help a lot to others.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my test code and it will print the last_modified datetime of objects which have the datetime after what I set.

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
response = s3.Bucket('<bucket name>').objects.all()

for item in response:
    obj = s3.Object(item.bucket_name, item.key)
    if obj.last_modified > datetime(2019, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc):
        print(obj.last_modified)
```

If you have a specific date, then

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
response = s3.Bucket('<bucket name>').objects.all()

date = '20190827' # input('Insert Date as a form YYYYmmdd')

for item in response:
    obj = s3.Object(item.bucket_name, item.key)
    if obj.last_modified.strftime('%Y%m%d') == date:
        print(obj.last_modified)
```

will give the results as follows.

```
2019-08-27 07:13:04+00:00
2019-08-27 07:13:36+00:00
2019-08-27 07:13:39+00:00
```

Comment: So if I want to check a specific date from the _last_modified_  method. I can check like this  `obj.last_modified==date` right?

Answer (score 0):

If edited [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918960/boto3-to-download-all-files-from-a-s3-bucket/56267603#56267603) to download all files *after* a certain timestamp and then write the current time to a file for use in the next iteration. You can easily adapt this to only download files of a specific date, month, year, yesterday, etc.

```
import os
import boto3
import datetime
import pandas as pd

### Load AWS Key, Secret and Region 
# ....
###

# Open file to read last download time and update file with current time
latesttime_file = "latest request.txt"
with open(latesttime_file, 'r') as f:
    latest_download = pd.to_datetime(f.read(), utc=True)

with open(latesttime_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(datetime.datetime.utcnow()))

# Initialize S3-client
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         region_name=AWS_REGION,  
                  aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY_ID, 
                  aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET) 


def download_dir(prefix, local, bucket, timestamp, client=s3_client):
    """
    params:
    - prefix: pattern to match in s3
    - local: local path to folder in which to place files
    - bucket: s3 bucket with target contents
    - client: initialized s3 client object
    """
    keys = []
    dirs = []
    next_token = ''
    base_kwargs = {
        'Bucket':bucket,
        'Prefix':prefix,
    }
    while next_token is not None:
        kwargs = base_kwargs.copy()
        if next_token != '':
            kwargs.update({'ContinuationToken': next_token})
        results = client.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
        contents = results.get('Contents')
        for i in contents:
            k = i.get('Key')
            t = i.get('LastModified')
            if k[-1] != '/':
                if t > timestamp:
                    keys.append(k)
            else:
                dirs.append(k)
        next_token = results.get('NextContinuationToken')
    for d in dirs:
        dest_pathname = os.path.join(local, d)
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname))
    for k in keys:
        dest_pathname = os.path.join(local, k)
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname))
        client.download_file(bucket, k, dest_pathname)

download_dir(<prefix or ''>, <local folder to download to>, <bucketname>, latest_download)
```